# Rational fraction constructions with origami

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry, origami

I'm writing a paper on origami in maths and currently looking at approximating rational fractions using various methods: crossing diagonals, Fujimoto, Haga, Noma methods.

Reading Origami and Geometric Constructions by Robert J. Lang page 14:

I would be very grateful if someone could explain why the bottom edge is divided into fractions $y=w/(w+x)$ and $z=x/(w+x)$

(assuming the $w$ on the right side of the pic is meant to be an $x$)

[image: crossing diagonals origami pic]

Comment: "divided into fractions" is not as clear as it might be: "divided in the ratios" might be better. In any case, the assumption is that $y+z=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By similar triangles, and assuming $y+z=1$, we have $y=\dfrac{h}{x}$ and $z=\dfrac{h}{w}$. This means that
$$\dfrac{h}{x}+\dfrac{h}{w}=1$$
and rearranging gives
$$h=\frac{wx}{w+x}$$